# Zurb foundation - remove the background colour from buttons?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

How do I remove the background colour from buttons in Zurb Foundation?

```
<button class="button button-arrow">Button <i class="icon-arrow-right">&rarr;</i></button>
```

CSS/ LESS:

```
.button-arrow {
    background-color: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: @text-font-size;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;

    &:hover {
        background-color: none;
        color: @colour-dark;
    }
}
```

Does not work obviously. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to : **initial**, this is the default value of the background-color property

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the .button class:

```
.button {
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Make sure your Foundation overrides are in a stylesheet loaded AFTER Foundation styles are loaded so you can use specificity to override them.

[The Foundation docs also talk about using SASS to edit the default variables controlling button styles](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/button.html):

> The default styles of this component can be customized using these
>   Sass variables in your project's settings file.
>
> $button-background